# how to raise a alert dialog from broadcast receiver with listof events?

Tags: android, android-listview, push-notification

> when ever i get a notification from gcm i need to raise a alert dialog with list of events in that dialog.i do that by using the custom toast message.but i am unable to write the clicking event for the list in the alert dialog box.
>   I call this method when ever i get new notification.alert dialog is appear but onclick event is not working for the list..

```
public void displayToast()
{
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
    View myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.statusbar, null);
    Toast toast = new Toast(con.getApplicationContext());
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
    TextView tv = (TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.notificationtype);
    ListView lv = (ListView) myView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    lv.setAdapter(new StatusAdapter(con, list));
    tv.setText("MESSAGES");

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (list.get(arg2).getType().equals("S Notification")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(con,ViewEventActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("eventid", list.get(arg2).getId());
                it.putExtra("event", "team");
                con.startActivity(it);
                //dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (list.get(arg2).getType().equals("S R Notification")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(con,GameDetailsActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("id", list.get(arg2).getId());
                con.startActivity(it);
                //dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (list.get(arg2).getType().equals("A Notification")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(con,ViewItemActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", "" + list.get(arg2).getId());
                con.startActivity(intent);
                //dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (list.get(arg2).getType().equals("D Notification")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(con,PersonalDetails.class);
                it.putExtra("personId", list.get(arg2).getId());
                con.startActivity(it);
                //dialog.dismiss();
            }
            if (list.get(arg2).getType().equals("M Notification")) {
                Intent it = new Intent(con,MessageContentActivity.class);
                it.putExtra("messageid", list.get(arg2).getId());
                con.startActivity(it);
            //  dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setDuration(1800000);
    toast.setView(myView);
    toast.show();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toast Window has the property `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` set by the framework,

So any Views that you have cannot be sent events to it.

Comment: ok thank you... i resolve this issue by using this  http://nsamteladze.blogspot.in/2012/10/show-dialog-in-android-after-device.html